# EF Core group by date and count value for previous dates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core

I have a table like

```
Date        Balance A   Balance B
---------------------------------
2022.03.01  100         200
2022.03.01  200         500
2022.03.02  300         600
2022.03.02  50          100
2022.03.03  150         300
2022.03.03  200         700
2022.03.04  450         500
2022.03.04  600         100
```

And I need to group by Date and get total balance for the date and also for previous dates.

I can do it like:

```
var groupedData = from d in _myContext.Balances 
                  group d by d.Date into dg
                  select new 
                         { 
                             Date = dg.Key, 
                             TotalBalanceA = dg.Sum(t => t.BalanceA),
                             TotalBalanceB = dg.Sum(t => t.BalanceB),
                             PreviousTotalA = ?,
                             PreviousTotalB = ?
                         }
```

But I'm not sure how to get total for previous dates.

So, if we take the table above, we should get grouped data like:

```
Date        TotalBalanceA   TotalBalanceB   PreviousTotalA  PreviousTotalB
2022.03.01  300             700             0               0
2022.03.02  350             700             300             700
2022.03.03  350             1000            650             1400
2022.03.04  1050            700             1000            2400
```

Update: I want to get these data from db. It is an `IQueryable`.

Comment: It looks like you have your data already. You can `.AsEnumerable()` it then use the `.Select()` with the index overload to select from previous records.

Comment: No, it's  IQuerable

Comment: Yes, I could work with Enumerable data, but I need the query run on SQL side, because there should be a lot of data like a 100000 or more

Comment: First of all, you can only do, what you be able to do with TSQL. So how would you do this on SQL side? Second, why do you think it should be done by SQL? I don't see eny query time benifits. It's just calculations, not a post processing filtering. So ordering by `Date`and putting the `Previous` values should be okay

Comment: @DemetriusAxenowski The main reason to make it on SQL that I want to apply pagination for the data

Comment: @AlanPschenovich that makes sense. What is the default sort order? if it can be different and is not by `Date`, then it will be tricky. And how you think to implement pagination with grouping?

Comment: Sort order will be by date. Seems I can deal with that with nested SQL SELECT. something like: PreviousTotalA  = _myContext.Balances.Where(bb=>bb.Date < dg.Key).Sum(bb=>bb.BalanceA)

Comment: That's going to be really slow (it's a triangular join), whereas in pure SQL you can just use window functions such as `SUM(BalanceA) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` which is far more efficient. Pagination is another problem: you don't want to paginate by row-number but by key (so seek to a key and read from there)

Comment: If sort order is by `Date` you can just query from date-1, then do the post processing in code

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF

Comment: Which EF? Version?

Comment: I'm using ef core 5

Comment: Ok, last answer, are you OK to use third party extension? Otherwise you have to go  with the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use subqueries?

```
var groupedData = from d in _myContext.Balances 
                    group d by d.Date into dg
                    select new 
                    { 
                        Date = dg.Key, 
                        TotalBalanceA = dg.Sum(t=>t.BalanceA),
                        TotalBalanceB = dg.Sum(t=>t.BalanceB),
                        PreviousTotalA = _myContext.Balances.Where(b => b.Date <= dg.Key).Sum(b => b.BalanceA),
                        PreviousTotalB = _myContext.Balances.Where(b => b.Date <= dg.Key).Sum(b => b.BalanceB)
                    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the subselect and it isnot perfomant. So What I did is used raw sql query with window functions

Comment: Also there is a lib linqtodb but I've never used it.